# PDOExceptionERROR 42000 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, wamp

I'm using the wamp server but unfortunately, I face a problem that I can't solve. Please someone find the error from my code and tell me How can I solve it?

##While I am trying to get data from the request id by PDO method, I'm getting the following errors##

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>`

<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['form1'])) 
    {
        $q = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE slider SET 
                slider_title=?,
                slider_subtitle=?,
                slider_buttontext=?,
                slider_buttonurl=?,
                WHERE slider_id=?
            ");
        $q->execute(array(
                $_POST['slider_title'],
                $_POST['slider_sub_title'],
                $_POST['slider_button_text'],
                $_POST['slider_button_url'],
                $_REQUEST['id']
        ));
     
        $success_message = "Slider Information Is Updated Successfully";
    }
?>
<?php
    $q= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM slider WHERE slider_id=?");
    $q->execute([$_REQUEST['id']]);
    $res= $q->fetchAll();
    foreach ($res as $row) {
        $slider_title = $row['slider_title'];
        $slider_subtitle = $row['slider_subtitle'];
        $slider_buttontext = $row['slider_buttontext'];
        $slider_buttonurl = $row['slider_buttonurl'];
        $slider_photo = $row['slider_img'];
    }
?>
```

The browser output is like the below text

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE slider_id='9'' at line 6 in F:\wamp\www\hotel\admin\slider_edit.php on line 18

Comment: `slider_buttonurl=?,  WHERE` Remove the comma, it's breaking your query

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. From your title/error and the tag [[tag:wamp]] (Windows, Apache, **MySQL**, and PHP), you are clearly using MySQL, *not* SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use comma in last field in sql statment

```
  if (isset($_POST['form1'])) 
    {
        $q = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE slider SET 
                slider_title=?,
                slider_subtitle=?,
                slider_buttontext=?,
                slider_buttonurl=?, // <- here - remove this comma
                WHERE slider_id=?
```

Comment: We dont answer TYPO's, we make a comment as above and then close and delete the question as typo's are never any use to others